# Help me identify the roughed in pipes please

Tags: plumbing, rough-in

Can you help me identify the roughed in pipes in my basement?

[image]

A.2" pipe. Buried in the ground. I think for the shower drain?

B.2" pipe. Not sure about this one

C.4.5" pipe. Pretty sure for the toilet

D.2" pipe. Goes all the way to the ceiling. I think for the sink/vanity. Does it also double as my vent pipe?
Also a bathroom directly above that as well. Could it be tied into that one as well?

Comment: `Could it be tied into that one as well?` ... run water in the upstairs bathroom and put your ear against the pipe downstairs

Comment: I can hear water so it must also be also the drain foe the upstairs washroom. Does that means it denfitley can't be my vent for the basement bathroom as well?